# Remove dublicates value from json array in android

Tags: java, android, json

[image: This is current result] [image: THIS IS REQUIRE RESULT][{"product_name":"13X25","ask_size":0,"product_id":"5","category_id":"1","quantity":"10","image":null,"description":"","product_pdf":null,"head":"MARSHAL","price":"22.00","user_quantity":"2"},{"product_name":"14X25","ask_size":0,"product_id":"6","category_id":"1","quantity":"12","image":null,"description":"","product_pdf":null,"head":"MARSHAL","price":"23.00","user_quantity":"1"},{"product_name":"14X25 C","ask_size":0,"product_id":"2","category_id":"1","quantity":"23","image":null,"description":"","product_pdf":null,"head":"KANGARO","price":"22.00","user_quantity":"0"},{"product_name":"17X25 C","ask_size":0,"product_id":"1","category_id":"1","quantity":"18","image":null,"description":"","product_pdf":null,"head":"HOKO","price":"12.00","user_quantity":"0"}]

This is my JSON array
Where I want to remove a particular key if it is already exist

There is a key named "head": "MARSHAL", This Key comes two times but I want to fetch it only one time.

If it's coming then it must be removed automatically from other JSONObject, Not only for one key

it can be to other keys also if they get repeated then I want them only one time and after that add that JSON data to the list

How can I do it for android?

I want to show this data into cardView adapter

Comment: The json you posted is fine, It's an array of four json objects, and all of them have only one `head` key.

Comment: ya but I want to remove that key it comes duplicate

Comment: You want to remove only the key or the entire object entry?

Comment: I want to remove the key like There is a key named "head": "MARSHAL", This is comes two times  i want to remove the second one and i want that this happens every time

Comment: I understand that this json comes from backend right? Then you have a backend issue

Comment: Yes it comes from backend but i have to figure it out at my side in android side

Comment: or can you suggest what changes should i need to tell to my backend developer so he can made chnages in json and my problem get solved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, convert your JSON to List<Map<String, Object>>.
You can use ObhectMapper to do so.

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type.TypeReference;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;

public class Test {
  private static ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    List<Map<String, String>> listOfMap = createListMap();

    Map<String, List<String>> tempMap = new HashMap<>();
    listOfMap.forEach(
        map -> {
          Set<String> keySet = new HashSet<>(map.keySet());
          keySet.forEach(
              key -> {
                List<String> tempValue = tempMap.get(key);
                if (Objects.nonNull(tempValue) && tempValue.contains(map.get(key))) {
                  map.remove(key);
                } else {
                  tempMap.put(key, Arrays.asList(map.get(key)));
                }
              });
        });
    System.out.println(createListMap(listOfMap));
  }

  private static List<Map<String, String>> createListMap() throws IOException {
    File jsonFile = new File("src/main/resources/input.json");
    return mapper.readValue(jsonFile, new TypeReference<List<Map<String, String>>>() {});
  }

  private static String createListMap(List<Map<String, String>> listOfMap) throws IOException {
    return mapper.writeValueAsString(listOfMap);
  }
}
```

Below is the output for your input JSON.

> [{"product_name":"13X25","ask_size":"0","product_id":"5","category_id":"1","quantity":"10","image":null,"description":"","product_pdf":null,"head":"MARSHAL","price":"22.00","user_quantity":"2"},{"product_name":"14X25","product_id":"6","quantity":"12","price":"23.00","user_quantity":"1"},{"product_name":"14X25
> C","product_id":"2","quantity":"23","head":"KANGARO","price":"22.00","user_quantity":"0"},{"product_name":"17X25
> C","product_id":"1","quantity":"18","head":"HOKO","price":"12.00"}]

May this serves your purpose.

Comment: will i need any dependency for ObjectMapper can you please post the full code so I can understand it properly

Comment: User jackson-databind library for the OnjectMapper.

Comment: Can you please tell me how can i add this to the  POJO list and use that for the adapater class

Comment: I have fetch this data from Server By usind volley

Comment: Can you please update the question with all the requirements you have? Because as per your question I have provided you the solution. Now if you need further assistance then you need to elaborate on that part.

Comment: I Want to show this data into card view after removing the duplicate DATA  Thanks For your help in advanced

Comment: I have also attached the image to serve my purpose

Comment: Then just simply convert new JSON to your desired List of objects;

Comment: can you please help how can i do it I am new to android and java